# Python 2048 Game

Tags: python, project

I have a project in which I have to do a 2048 game.

Right now, I'm on the function that sums numbers if they are equal and it should also pull them up if there is a 0 between numbers.

Basically this is what I've done:

```
'''tab creates the 2048 game board'''
def tab():
    return ({
        (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 0,
        (2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (2, 3): 0, (2, 4): 0,
        (3, 1): 0, (3, 2): 0, (3, 3): 0, (3, 4): 0,
        (4, 1): 0, (4, 2): 0, (4, 3): 0, (4, 4): 0
        })

#tab_reduc(t,d) gets a board(t) and a place to move as a string ('N','S','E','W') and moves the board as ordered
def tab_reduc(t,d):
    for i in range(1,4):
        for c in range(1,4):
            if t[(i,c)] == t[(i,c+1)] and t[(i,c+1)] != 0:
                t[(i,c)] = t[(i,c)] + t[(i,c+1)]
                t[(i,c+1)] = 0

            elif t[(i,c)] != t[(i,c+1)] and t[(i,c)] != 0:
                t[(i,c)] = t[(i,c)]
                t[(i,c+1)] = t[(i,c+1)]

            elif t[(i,c)] == 0 and t[(i,c+1)] != 0:
                t[(i,c)] = t[(i,c+1)]
                t[(i,c+1)] = 0

    return t
```

For example, If I have:

```
(1,1) = 4
(1,2) = 4
(1,3) = 8
(1,4) = 4
```

when I run "tab_reduc(t,'N')" the game should go up , and I do get

```
(1,1) = 8
(1,2) = 8
(1,3) = 4
(1,4) = 0
```

but if I have

```
(1,1) = 4
(1,2) = 0
(1,3) = 0
(1,4) = 4
```

and I do the North play, I get

```
(1,1) = 4
(1,2) = 0
(1,3) = 4
(1,4) = 0
```

and if I do it again, I'll get:

```
(1,1) = 4
(1,2) = 4
(1,3) = 0
(1,4) = 0
```

and again:

```
(1,1) = 8
(1,2) = 0
(1,3) = 0
(1,4) = 0
```

problem is, this should be done in 1 play, and not several plays.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: So what's your questions?

Comment: You need to have special logic for `0` to count as empty space and allow the movement to continue.

Comment: I'd love to know what's making my code fail. Since, what is been done in 3 times should be done in 1 time.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure how could I go about that?

Comment: It is __impossible__ to reason about your code until you __fix your indentation__ and the bug in `tab()` that will cause the posted code to not even pass a syntax check.

Comment: it's running fine, it got bugged on the stackoverflow "special code  stuffy" that almost didn't even let me post the code lol

Comment: So you're telling me that your code in `tab()` which has unbalanced parentheses and braces is working fine?

Comment: I edited the functions name in order to post it here, since it's written in my mother language, which I doubt you would understand, which might have made a bug somewhere. I can print screen it if you want lol

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/J6P4HKN.png

Comment: @AndréSoares: I've taken the code from your image and matched the indentation in the question.

Comment: Thank you, so could anyone help me now, since it seems everything has been fixed on the formmating on the thread...

Answer (score 1):

#### Thoughts...

When moving `N`, you probably want to iterate backwards.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    for c in reversed(range(1, 4)):
        ...
```

#### Therefore...

If you do that fix, you'll get closer to your solution. However, you'll still have a bug in this case:

```
0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
```

Which your improved code would then produce:

```
8 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

When it should produce:

```
4 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader. I imagine that the easiest way to fix that is to break out of the iteration when you successfully do an accumulation.

#### And some final thoughts:

If I was to implement this myself, I'd use a slightly different strategy. The key here is to break up the problem into steps. Let's continue by only talking about North.

Steps:

1. Let's remove all `0`s above the numbers. That is, let's flatten the table northward. So this:

   ```
   0 0 0 0             1 1 0 1
   1 0 0 0  Becomes..  0 0 0 1
   0 1 0 1             0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 1             0 0 0 0
   ```
2. Next, let's look at neighbors and merge them if we can. So:

   ```
   0 0 0 1             0 0 0 2
   0 0 0 1  Becomes..  0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 1             0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 0             0 0 0 0
   ```
3. Step three is to remove 0s again. We need to do this because we inserted some extra ones in the previous step.

   ```
   0 0 0 1             0 0 0 2
   0 0 0 1  Becomes..  0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 1             0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0             0 0 0 0
   ```

Now. How might we implement something like this in code?

```
def tab():
    return ({
        (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 0,
        (2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0, (2, 3): 0, (2, 4): 0,
        (3, 1): 0, (3, 2): 0, (3, 3): 0, (3, 4): 0,
        (4, 1): 0, (4, 2): 0, (4, 3): 0, (4, 4): 0
        })

def tab_reduc(t,d):
    if d in ('n', 'N'):
        # Merge whitespace
        for _ in range(4): # FIXME: Massive hack...
            for i in range(1,4):
                for c in range(1,5):
                    if t[i+0, c] == 0 and t[i+1, c] != 0:
                        t[i+0, c] = t[i+1, c]
                        t[i+1, c] = 0

        # Merge neighbors
        for i in reversed(range(1, 4)):
            for c in range(1,5):
                if t[i+0, c] == t[i+1, c] and t[i, c] != 0:
                    t[i+0, c] *= 2
                    t[i+1, c] = 0

        # Merge whitespace
        for _ in range(4): # FIXME: Massive hack
            for i in range(1,4):
                for c in range(1,5):
                    if t[i+0, c] == 0 and t[i+1, c] != 0:
                        t[i+0, c] = t[i+1, c]
                        t[i+1, c] = 0

def tab_print(t):
    for i in range(1, 5):
        for c in range(1, 5):
            print '{:2d}'.format(t[i,c]),
        print
    print

t = tab()
t[(1,4)] = 2
t[(2,4)] = 2
t[(3,4)] = 2
t[(4,4)] = 2
tab_print(t)
tab_reduc(t, 'N')
tab_print(t)
```

#### Runtime output:

```
 0  0  0  2
 0  0  0  2
 0  0  0  2
 0  0  0  2

 0  0  0  4
 0  0  0  4
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
```

I've changed a few internal things for my own sanity. In this code, `(i, j)` is `i-1` rows down, and `j-1` columns to the right.

Comment: It's not, It's in line with the 1st for (for i in range(1,4))

Comment: as I've said, it was due to the formatting that stack overflow takes, it's my 1st time posting here, and for who knows what, i couldn't post it, so I tried everything until I could post it.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me quite a lot. I had though about that, but then I have to find a way to fix that bug. Thanks!

Comment: And Yes, I was aware of that! But my code does +1 to l so if l goes from 1 to 4 == [1,2,3] then in the code it will run to 4 because of the +1 I do. If I do 1 to 5, it will go out of range.

Comment: @AndréSoares: Yeah. That was a mistake on my end. I've since edited that out of my answer. I think the key thing you were looking for here was the reverse iteration. I've also edited that to be cleaner by using the builtin `reversed`.

Comment: There's still a problem tho, I do get the bug you said, but I also get the bug that if:
4 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
4 0 0 0

gets me:
8 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
8 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

Comment: @AndréSoares: You might also notice that `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2` does nothing as well.

Comment: So back to stack 0... damn it... how could I go around this?

Comment: @AndréSoares: I've added some final thoughts. You may find it helpful.

Comment: I did find it helpful, but I tested it and it did actually, nothing? I do understand your approach tho, Myself though about it but I though it would be more complicated...

Comment: @AndréSoares: I don't follow? I included output in the answer showing it working. (Although I found that the example in your original question didn't work due to a small bug that I added a small hack to fix in the 0s removal part)

Comment: What I meant was, I just copied your code and tried it for myself, and it didn't do anything, it didn't change the t (board)

Comment: @AndréSoares: Perhaps there was an error when you copied it? When I run it locally or on ideone.com, it works as I would expect: http://ideone.com/E4ENLm

Comment: I have no idea what's happening, but whenever I copy it to my IDE, it doesn't work???

Comment: 'I've changed a few internal things for my own sanity. In this code, (i, j) is i-1 rows down, and j-1 columns to the right.'
What do you mean by this?

Comment: @AndréSoares: Your original code said that `(1, 2)` was directly above `(1,1)`. The way I normally work `(2, 1)` would be directly above `(1, 1)`. I just made that change to help me keep things straight when writing my version.

Comment: Would it affect anything if I copy pasted it into the rest of my code? Because it's still not working... which is weird.

Comment: After some modifications I got it going, now I have a problem for South play... Could you give me some hints? I though I just had to reverse everything, but it seems I was wrong.